# How to compare two files in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, diff

I want to compare two files. One is in the current project and the other is in the backup directory. I know how to compare if they were in the same project.
How can I compare in Eclipse?
And what is Flex navigator in Eclipse?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Open the Navigator with the Main menu: *Window->Show View->Navigator*.

You can select two or more files in the Navigator using *Ctrl-click*, or *Command-click* in OSX. Now *Right-click* any one of the selected files, and select the menu item: *Compare With->Each Other*.

The problem is that your alternate file might not be in the Navigator, e.g. your backup directory isn't listed in the Navigator. If not, *Right-click* in the Navigator and choose  the menu item: *New->Folder*. In the resulting dialog click the *Advanced>>* button beneath the *Folder Name* field, choose *Link to alternate location (Linked Folder)*, and browse to add your backup directory.

Now using the Navigator you'll be able to select the two files, and use *Compare With*.

You can similarly compare files using e.g. the Package Explorer.

Comment: In OSX, it is command-click for selecting multiple files. Thank you.

Comment: When I go to `Window->Show View->Other` then I see `Navigator (deprecated)` and then when I right-click on a file and click on `Compare With` then `Each Other` is disabled.