# Is there a way of comparing two open files without using package explorer/project/navigator?

Tags: java, eclipse, compare

For large projects I dont want to be manually finding files on the left- navigator/project-explorer or package explorer. It takes too much time if project has hundreds of files.

How can I compare two files that are open in editor?:

[image]

I looked up other answers and could not find what I need. This post shows how to do it using navigator (not what I need). [How to compare two files in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12334593/how-to-compare-two-files-in-eclipse)

**UPDATE:**

I do not want to be finding other file manually in project/navigator/whatever. Takes too long.

**UPDATE2**

- AnyEdit eclipse plugin suggested by ngueno helps speeding up comparison.
  Even though I still need to use side-bar/explorer it speeds up the work.
- At the time of writing this post this problem was recognized by Eclipse community (https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=224562).

Comment: Most editors have 'Show In > Package Explorer/Navigator/Project Explorer' in the right click context menu. This will show the file quickly in the view.

Comment: I know that. then you have to scroll across 500 files to get the other file :/.

Comment: I usually hit the "collapse all" button before using "Show in Package Explorer", it helps a bit to reduce scrolling. Also activating "link with editor" is useful to locate files faster than using "Show in ..."

Comment: Have you consider using an application designed for comparing, like Beyond Compare (https://www.scootersoftware.com/)?

Comment: Thanks @kapex collapse all will not help if you have loads of files in same package, or you our file is a subpackage within loads of other packages.

Comment: @TungstenX I used BeyondCompare, kdiff3, diffs etc. But I do not want to switch to external application if Eclipse has built in comparer that works sufficiently ok. Seems to me that Eclipse is missing this feature.

Comment: @WitoldKaczurba considering you know the class name, probably it should be easy opening it using Ctrl+R and using the compare tool

Comment: To _UPDATE2_: The _Compare With_ right-click menu is also available in the active text-based editor. You can also add a shortcut in _Window > Preferences: General > Keys_ for the command _Compare with Open Editor..._ to compare the active editor (or the selected file) with another open editor which is the fastest option I can think of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do that using the Eclipse, after installing the [AnyEdit plugin](http://andrei.gmxhome.de/anyedit/index.html) (can be found on Eclipse Marketplace)

The plugin will show the following option:

[image]

This will show a selection dialog to you choose which editor you want to compare:

[image]

And after the selection:

[image]

There are a few discussion around this feature in the bugs [224562](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=224562) and [39126](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=39126), they also mention the AnyEdit workaround. It seems they did not have anyone from the community available to work on this improvement yet.

Comment: This helps a lot. Upvoting.

Comment: @WitoldKaczurba If you want to have the feature built into Eclipse, you should also vote for and comment on [Eclipse bug 224562](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=224562). The author of AnyEdit, Andrei Loskutov, is also an Eclipse committer.

Comment: Who are _they_? Unlike Mozilla, there is no development team employed by Eclipse, but people who contribute to Eclipse in their work or in their spare time.

Comment: @howlger the community, as mentioned in 2011 by Tomasz *No, it's still waiting for a volunteer.*

Comment: @ngueno The code already exists written by an Eclipse developer. But the few votes for the bug indicate that there is not much interest in this feature. In open source, it works quite well to say what you want. What doesn't work is silence or complaining (which unfortunately some people do who don't understand the concept of open source). By the way, almost all of my contributions to Eclipse and to other open source projects have been accepted.

Comment: @howlger OK. Voted for it on Eclipse. Cheers.